# spring security oauth2 multiple ResourceServerTokenServices

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have two sets of resource APIs, each of which must be validated against distinct remote authorization servers.

Below is my security-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd">

    <authentication-manager>
    </authentication-manager>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceFilterA"
                           token-services-ref="tokenServicesA"/>

    <http pattern="/v1/A/**"
          request-matcher="ant"
          disable-url-rewriting="true"
          use-expressions="true"
          entry-point-ref="entryPointA">

      <intercept-url pattern="/v1/A/endpoint1"
                     method="GET"
                     access="hasAuthority('scope.A')"/>

      <anonymous enabled="true"/>
      <csrf disabled="true"/>

      <custom-filter ref="resourceFilterA" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    </http>


    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceFilterB"
                           token-services-ref="tokenServicesB"/>

    <http pattern="/v1/B/**"
          request-matcher="ant"
          disable-url-rewriting="true"
          use-expressions="true"
          entry-point-ref="entryPointB">

      <intercept-url pattern="/v1/B/endpoint1"
                     method="POST"
                     access="hasAuthority('scope.B')"/>


      <anonymous enabled="true"/>
      <csrf disabled="true"/>

      <custom-filter ref="resourceFilterB" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    </http>

</b:beans>
```

The `tokenServicesA` and `tokenServicesB` are defined in Java config:

```
@Bean
public OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPointA() {
    return new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
}


@Bean
public OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPointB() {
    return new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
}

@Bean
public ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServicesA() {
    FastRemoteTokenServices tokenServices = new FastRemoteTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setUseHttps(true);
    tokenServices.setStoreClaims(true);
    tokenServices.setTrustedIssuerIdsRegex(
            Pattern.compile(trustedIssuerA, Pattern.LITERAL).pattern());
    return tokenServices;
}

@Bean
public ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServicesB() {
    FastRemoteTokenServices tokenServices = new FastRemoteTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setUseHttps(true);
    tokenServices.setStoreClaims(true);
    tokenServices.setTrustedIssuerIdsRegex(
            Pattern.compile(trustedIssuerB, Pattern.LITERAL).pattern());
    return tokenServices;
}
```

I expected exactly one of the filters to match the request based on the mutually exclusive intercept-url patterns in the http blocks.

However, it appears that for the sample request logged below which bears a token from trusted issuer A, while the first http tag does match and successfully authenticates the request, that the trusted issuer in the token is still checked against the trusted issuer B regexp, which fails.

Similarly, a request with a token from trusted issuer B is also matched against the regexp of trusted issuer A, which also fails.

```
estMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/v1/A/endpoint1'; against '/v1/A/endpoint1'                                                                 
2018-02-20 21:46:09.879 DEBUG 8439 --- [io-12525-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInt
erceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /v1/A/endpoint1; Attribu
tes: [hasAuthority('scope.A')]                
2018-02-20 21:46:09.879 DEBUG 8439 --- [io-12525-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInt
erceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.O
Auth2Authentication@cc91d34f: Principal: apg-client; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authent
icated: true; Details: remoteAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, tokenType=BearertokenValue=<TOKE
N>; Granted Authorities: scope.A
2018-02-20 21:46:10.110 DEBUG 8439 --- [io-12525-exec-4] o.s.s.access.vote.Affirmative
Based       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionV
oter@a7694fd, returned: 1                                                            
2018-02-20 21:46:10.110 DEBUG 8439 --- [io-12525-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInt
erceptor    : Authorization successful                                               
2018-02-20 21:46:10.110 DEBUG 8439 --- [io-12525-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInt
erceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object                      
2018-02-20 21:46:10.110 DEBUG 8439 --- [io-12525-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainP
roxy        : /v1/A/endpoint1 reached end of additional filter chain; procee
ding with original chain                                                             
2018-02-20 21:46:10.111 DEBUG 8439 --- [io-12525-exec-4] p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProce
ssingFilter : Authentication request failed: error="invalid_token", error_description=
"The issuer 'https://my.issuer.A/oauth/token' is not trusted because it does not match
the regex '<my-issuer-B-regexp>'
2018-02-20 21:46:10.112 DEBUG 8439 --- [io-12525-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContex
tRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be
 stored in HttpSession.                                                              
2018-02-20 21:46:10.113 DEBUG 8439 --- [io-12525-exec-4] s.s.o.p.e.DefaultOAuth2Except
ionRenderer : Written [error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer 'https://m
y.issuer.A/oauth/token' is not trusted because it does not match the regex '<my-issuer
-B-regexp>' /json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Mappin
gJackson2Htt pMessageConverter@25743461]                                                          
2018-02-20 21:46:10.113 DEBUG 8439 --- [io-12525-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslatio
nFilter     : Chain processed normally                                               
2018-02-20 21:46:10.113 DEBUG 8439 --- [io-12525-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersis
tenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed     
2018-02-20 21:46:10.113 DEBUG 8439 --- [io-12525-exec-4] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestConte
xtFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.Requ
estFacade@74f7a53b
```

What is the fundamental mistake in the configuration above?

Alternatively, what is a good reference example with multiple oauth resource servers, each protected by a distinct FastRemoteTokenServices token service?

Comment: If you have two distinct authorization servers and two distinct resource server, why you put both resource server in the same application? Make two WARs and deploy them independently. It is much easier.

Comment: the application hosts both resources (pulled from the same DB, so it wouldn't make sense to split into a different application), but it does not host any of the authorization servers, they are both remote

Comment: I disagree, if the resource servers are independently, it would make vermy much sense to split them. Sharing the same database is no good reason to put it together.

Comment: in fact, the resource is only one. but authorization is respected from more than one trusted issuer. I don't see a problem.

Comment: @ealfonso did you resolved this issue? I have same issue and hope your solution.